# Log Cleaning in Magento 2 periodically

Tags: magento2, log, magento-cron

I am trying to clean the log generated in `var/log` folder in magento 2 by cron job so that it can run periodically.I go through this link https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-db-log-cleaner/blob/master/Rakeshmagento/Logcleaner/Cron/Logcleaner.php . In this way  I can delete some specific file from db. `Debug.log`,`System.log`,`exception.log` remain as it is.I want to delete these file also.
Needing help in this regard.
Thank you

Comment: do you still need the log cleaner for the log files?